# MySQL retrieve from different table if empty

Tags: mysql

I have this query that is getting `CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE` from the isrc_codes table. But if `TRACK_ISRC` is empty I need it to get `CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE` from the `albums` table. Is there a way to do that with MySQL. On the `albums` table `r.BUNDLE_ID = a.BUNDLE_ID` and it would be `a.CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE`. Here is my query

```
$add = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT sum(r.DISTRIBUTED_AMOUNT / r.EXCHANGE_RATE * i.CONTRACT_PERCENTAGE / 100)
FROM royalties r, isrc_codes i 
WHERE r.TRACK_ISRC = i.ISRC_CODE 
AND r.BUNDLE_ARTIST = '".$row['artistname']."' 
AND r.MONTH_ADDED = '".$current_month."'");
```

Comment: maybe you could try to build a view on isrc_codes and album tables, so you can join it? (not sure actually if this is possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to get NULL when there's no matching row in `isrc_codes`, and `IFNULL` to fall back to the column from `albums`.

```
$add = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(r.distributed_amount / r.exchange_rate * IFNULL(i.contract_percentage, a.contract_percentage) / 100)
                    FROM royalties r
                    LEFT JOIN isrc_codes i ON r.track_isrc = i.isrc_code
                    LEFT JOIN albums a ON r.bundle_id = a.bundle_id
                    WHERE r.bundle_artist = '{$row['artistname']}'
                    AND r.month_added = '$current_month'");
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given` on the last line

Comment: Couldn't you see that I accidentally left out the `$con` argument?

Comment: missed that, I'm also getting this error on fetch `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Comment: you should be checking for errors and printing `mysqli_error($con)` to see the error message.

Comment: I left the alias `a` out of the `LEFT JOIN albums` clause.